# Is it possible to have a new type parameter for a method of a parameterized type in Go?

Tags: go, generics, type-parameter

I'm trying to write a generic `List` container in Go so I can better learn how type parameters work.

Currently I'm working on a `Map` method that takes in a mapper function and returns a new list that has every element mapped.

Here is a part of the code:

```golang
type List[T any] []*T

func (list List[T]) Map[E](mapper func(int, *T) *E) List[E] {
    // Implementation details
}
```

This code will error out with *"method must have no type parameters"*. Is there a way to properly do it without using `List[interface{}]` as the out type?

Comment: No. You have to list all type parameters at the type declaration.

Comment: The solution is define a function Map that receive your list and other parameters. This limitation may be fixed in the next versions of go

Comment: See also the [Why does Go not support methods with type parameters?](https://go.dev/doc/faq#generic_methods) answer in the official Go FAQ, which includes:
"The methods of a type determines the interfaces that the type implements, but it is not clear how this would work with parameterized arguments for methods of generic types. It would require either instantiating functions at run time or instantiating every generic function for every possible type argument. Neither approach seems feasible."